# HidDevice.FromIdAsync returns null, how do I figure out why?

Tags: windows-runtime, hid, windows-8.1

I'm trying to get information from a HID supporting device in a windows 8.1 app. My app is capable of finding the device, when I do a DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(deviceSelector) the device is in the list.

But when I try to get a handle to the device using HidDevice.FromIdAsync, it returns null

How do I debug this issue to hopefully find the reason for getting a null reference back and not a HidDevice instance?

I've validated the following things already

- The device supports HID as I'm capable of connecting and reading from
  it using a winforms application and a generic hid driver
- VendorId, ProductId, UsageId and UsagePage are correct otherwise it
  could not be listed in the find all I assume
- The same values have also been specified in the app manifest
  capabilities
- The device is using built in drivers (I'm aware that 8.1 can't do
  supplier provided drivers)
- There are no warning or error entries in the operational logs
- I get the same behavior when using the devicewatcher, it finds the
  device but I can't get a reference to it

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Just by sheer luck we found the issue.. apparantly usagepage and usage were inverted in the app manifest.